# How do I make my webpage adjust its according to the screensize?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

On my Desktop monitor, the website is perfect, however, when I view it on my laptop, the content is out of place

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" charset="utf-8">
```

Have tried this.

```
width="100vw" height="100vh"
```

Have tried this too.

Have tried to set container's min and max-width/height.
None of it worked. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: yes you can do this using bootstrap gird system or flex https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/,
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/
or simple by using simple css

Comment: I am not very proficient in Web designing. However do you think I can make a flex container and put whatever I have now in it? Will it work? 

Also, what could be done in CSS?

Comment: using simple css you can do it by using  mediaqueries https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
yes step by step follow the example you will do it by your self
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use Media querys or incase of framework use the relevent class

### standard Media Query Sizes

```
320px — 480px: Mobile devices.
481px — 768px: iPads, Tablets.
769px — 1024px: Small screens, laptops.
1025px — 1200px: Desktops, large screens.
1201px and more — Extra large screens, TV.
```

### Example of bootstrap framework

```
col-xs for smaller Mobile phone (devices with resolutions < 576px);
col-sm for larger mobile phones (devices with resolutions ≥ 576px);
col-md for tablets (≥768px);
col-lg for laptops (≥992px);
col-xl for desktops (≥1200px)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

You are declaring `meta` tag incorrectly

- `charset` declares the document's character encoding
- `name` and `content` can be used together to provide document metadata

> NOTE: character encoding must be located entirely within the first
> 1024 bytes of the document.

## Solution

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)